# UIImageView animation starts a few seconds after startAnimating is issued

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

Ok, I have the following very simple animation composed of 25 frames in PNG format. Each frame is 320 × 360 and about 170Kb in size. Here is the code I use

.h:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *Animation_Normal_View;
```

In Interface Builder I have a UIImageView with a referencing outlet pointing to this. All my images are named normal_000_crop.png, normal_001_crop.png, normal_002_crop.png,...

.m:

```
Animation_Normal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:25];
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
  [Animation_Normal addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"normal_%03d_crop.png", i] ofType:nil]]];
}

Animation_Normal_View.animationImages = Animation_Normal;
Animation_Normal_View.animationDuration = 1; // seconds
Animation_Normal_View.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever
[Animation_Normal release];


[self.view addSubview:Animation_Normal_View];
[Animation_Normal_View startAnimating];
```

On the simulator everything loogs good visual animation start as soos as the startAnimating is issued.

But on the iPhone 3G running iOS 4.0.2, the visual animation starts a good 2 to 3 seconds after the startAnimating is issued.

I have tried about every technique on I could find in blogs or forum that should solve this to no avail.

Any hints appreciated even if it's a completly different way to to a PNG based animation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question and I will address it here with a few thoughts.

First, you are loading a series of graphics that are around 4MB in total size.  This may take a moment, especially on slower (older) devices.

In the *@interface* block of your **.h** file you may want to declare two properties such as:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *animationViewNormal;
NSMutableArray *animationViewNormalImages;
```

The first is the UIImageView that you already have (just renamed for best practices) and the second is a mutable array to hold the stack of images for the image view.  Let me state that if having "normal" implies state.  For clarification, are you loading additional sets of images for different states?

In your **.m** file in the *@interface* create the following method:

```
- (void)loadAnimationImages;
```

This will provide the function to lead the image stack to the mutable array defined in the header.

In the same **.m** file in the *@implementation* you'll want the following:

```
- (void)loadAnimationImages {
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"normalCrop%03u", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];
    if (image) {
      [animationViewNormalImages addObject:image];
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I renamed the PNG files from normal_%03u_crop to normalCrop%03u as it is best practice to put the index label at the end of the file name (also most apps will output the content this way).  The loop loads an image, checks to see that it is an image and then adds the image to the "image stack" in the mutable array.

In the *init()* you'll need the following:

```
- (id)init {
  ...
  animationViewNormalImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  ...
}
```

This allocates the (*animationViewNormalImages*) mutable array to hold your stack of images for the image view.

We'll now move on to the code for the *viewDidLoad()*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  ...
  [self loadAnimationImages];
  [animationViewNormal setAnimationImages:animationViewNormalImages];
  [animationViewNormal setAnimationDuration:1.1f];
  [animationViewNormal setAnimationRepeatCount:0];  //  0=infinite loop
  ...
}
```

We load the stack of images into the mutable array then set the properties of our imageView with the image stack, duration and repeat count.

Next in the *viewDidAppear()* we start the image view animating:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  ...
  [animationViewNormal startAnimating];
  ...
}
```

Once the imageView is animating as an infinite loop we need to handle when leaving the view in the *viewWillDisappear()*:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  ...
  [animationViewNormal stopAnimating];
  ...
}
```

Last (which should be the second thing we add the **.m** file) we cleanup in the mutable array in the *dealloc()*:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  ...
  [animationViewNormalImages release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

This is how we handle it and works for us, but then again, we're normally not loading 4MB of images into memory to animate.

The .PNG files are compressed when building the app and I am not sure if they are decompressed on the fly when loading the images our of the resource bundle.  This is a boolean value int he Build Properties Build Settings (COMPRESS_PNG_FILES).

For performance you may want to consider the following:

- Mark opaque views as such:
  Compositing a view whose contents are
  opaque requires much less effort than
  compositing one that is partially
  transparent. To make a view opaque,
  the contents of the view must not
  contain any transparency and the
  opaque property of the view must be
  set to YES.
- Remove alpha channels from opaque PNG
  files: If every pixel of a PNG image
  is opaque, removing    the alpha
  channel avoids the need to blend the
  layers containing that image. This
  simplifies compositing of the image
  considerably and improves drawing
  performance.

Furthermore, you may find it's better the make one large image with all 24 frames (offset by the width of the individual frame) and then load it once.  Then using Core Graphics with *CGContextClipToRect* then just offset the image context.  This means more code but may be faster than using the standard stack method.

Lastly, you may want to consider is converting the .PNG files into .PVR (PVRTC) files.  More information can be found here: [Apple Tech QA](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1611.html), [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html), and [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/Introduction/Intro.html).

I hope this helps and please vote it up if it does.

Best,
Kevin
Able Pear Software

Comment: Wow Kevin! Thanks for taking the time to write all this. I haven't digested all of it yet, but will read it very carefully.

Again thank you. That is what the software developer community is all about !

Answer (score 2):

imageWithContentsOfFile: tends to take a long time to process, especially if there are lots of files (25 is kind of a lot) and/or they're big.

One thing you can try is to switch it out for imageNamed:, i.e.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"normal_%03d_crop.png", i]]
```

imageNamed: is generally much faster, but tends to cache images more or less indefinitely.

If loading the images into memory and keeping them around throughout the whole app is unacceptable, you may need to do some tweaky things to load them in at an appropriate time and to unload them after they've been used. That stuff is always tricky, and requires multithreading to not block the main UI while loading. But doable. And there are examples.

Answer (score 0):

Load those images before using the start animating method . I advice an easier way " Just call start animating method in the applicationDidEnterForeground . When calling this one don't forget your UIImageView's alpha property . If you set uiimageiew.alpha=0.01; like this , your start animating method will be called and the user can't see this animation " so there will be no lag anymore.